# String conversion by inserting another string or character after particular counts

Tags: python, python-2.7

Send data on serial in hex format I have data in string format on 1st line which converted to hex string on 2nd line but while sending python - serial it should be in format on 3rd line. I want to insert `'\x'` initially and after every 2 count. please help for the same

```
1st line - string ='s00123'
2nd line - "01733030313233"
3rd lline - `x01\x73\x30\x30\x31\x32\x33`
```

Comment: 3rd lline - \x01\x73\x30\x30\x31\x32\x33

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about this. The cleanest I can think of off the top of my head would be to create a new `list` and add every two characters to that `list`, then `join` them all together with the added `\x`. There's probably a better way to do it using the `binascii` module, but I can't seem to think of any right now.

```
hexString = 'ab1234'
hexArray = list()
for i in range(0, len(hexString), 2):
    val = '\x' + hexString[i:i+2]
    hexArray.append(val)
finalResult = ''.join(hexArray)
```

Of course this code doesn't check for invalid input, so you're going to have to write some error checking into it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. one more logic i have. s = "f0cbf260e0ca8ec2431089fb393a1c29513aaaa5847d13e8be84760968e64dc6"
sx = r"\x" + r"\x".join(s[n : n+2] for n in range(0, len(s), 2))
print(sx)